# Broken images/videos after migration - DIVI theme- works ok on Mac OS

Tags: images, migration, videos

We recently moved hosts for our Divi site, but the domain stayed the same. Hosting company we joined offered free migration and looks like it was a mistake. After the migration our background videos arent working, some images as well. Media library in the backend shows blank page, Page editing window is broken. 
These are the errors I got from the console:

https://www.screencast.com/t/XUlIybumHN - frontend errors

https://www.screencast.com/t/OyBernSx8y3 - backend errors

I know that apart from standard Wordpress migration procedures there should be JSON import done on Divi, if this was neglected, is there a way of fixing this after migration? From what I read that could be serialized data in the database, can they be somehow fixed/repaired?

Now the best part.. the site(both frontend and backend) works well on Mac OS, but not on Windows platforms. So maybe there is some hope?

Comment: for giggles, can you go in to the theme settings and just hit save?

Comment: @rudtek Just tried with high hopes.. but that doesnt help unfortunately.